# Can you see anything in this foreach loop that would make it execute twice?

Tags: foreach

This is "psuedo code" from a workflow that I hope will be more readable than xaml or the design view. The top foreach loop "foreach (DataRow row in dataSetTables[0] as Enumerable())" seems to be executing twice. At least the 2 Rest Calls and the DB insert operation contained inside it are happening twice. I've no idea why a foreach would execute twice.

```
drpQryStr = "very long query string"
dataSet = new DataSet()
dataSet = ExecuteQuery
if dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0
    foreach (DataRow row in dataSetTables[0] as Enumerable())
        iter = 0
        dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        lst = new List<char>()
        newDict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        sb = new StringBuilder()

        Do
            dict.Add(row.Table.Columns[iter].ColumnName, row[row.Table.Columns[iter].ColumnName].ToString())
            iter ++
        While(iter < row.Table.Columns.Count)

        foreach (KeyValuePair kv in dict)
            if(kv.Key == "DOB" || kv.Key == "LOB")
                newDict.Add(kv.Key, kv.Value)
            else
                strKey = kv.Key
                strCaseCorrected = strKey.ToLower()
                aChars = strCaseCorrected.ToCharArray()
                lst.Clear()
                sb.Clear()
                lst.AddRange(aChars)
                itr2 = 0

                Do
                    if(itr2 == 0)
                        lst[itr2] = Char.ToUpper(lst[itr2])
                    else
                        if(lst[itr2] == '_')
                            itr2 ++
                            lst[itr2] = Char.ToUpper(lst[itr2])
                        else
                            if(lst.Count - itr2 == 1)
                                if(lst[itr2] == 'd')
                                    if(lst[itr2 - 1] == 'I')
                                        lst[itr2] = 'D'
                    itr2 ++
                While(itr2 < lst.Count)

                foreach(Char c in lst)
                    sb.Append(c.ToStrng()

                newDict.Add(sb.ToString(), kv.Value)

        dict = newDict
        dict[Communiction_Date] = dict["Communication_Date"].Insert(4, "-").Insert(7, "-")
        strJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict, Formatting.None)
        today = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
        Invoke a Rest Service that posts this json to a sqlless DB

        eventStr = "a large string that likely doesn't cause the problem"
        ctdbObj = JObject.Parse(eventStr)
        Invoke aRest Service that Posts an event to a sqlless DB

        cts_id = dict["External_Source_ID"]
        strInsert = "sql insert statement"
        Execute Insert statement
SendResponse
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah neither could I, I thnk the sql query may be running too long and the workflow is being invoked again before it finishes executing. Consider this closed.